# Downstream pipeline stuck without an error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've a pipeline say `Upstream` and it calls another pipeline say `Downstream`. But `Downstream` pipeline stuck for more than 10 hours with following console log -

```
Started by upstream project "Upstream" build number 456
originally caused by:
 Started by user XYZ
Running as SYSTEM
Building remotely on <ip-address> in workspace /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/Downstream
```

But this is not helping me to understand the cause and how to make it move ahead. Please help me on how I can debug this issue and resolve.